# Flipping specific positions of the same items in a list of lists structure

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

I have the following data structure:

```
pool = [[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"ze","Zero"],
[[0,0,3,0,3,0,0,0],"bd","BasicDilemma"],
[[0,0,3,2,3,0,0,2],"lk","LowLock"],
[[0,1,3,2,0,3,1,2],"DlCo",""],
[[0,1,3,2,0,3,2,1],"DlPc",""],
[[0,1,3,2,1,3,0,2],"DlAs",""],
[[0,1,3,2,1,3,2,0],"DlHa",""],
[[0,1,3,2,2,3,0,1],"DlSh",""],
[[0,1,3,2,2,3,1,0],"DlNc",""]]

def ListFlip (pool):
    for game in range (0, len(pool)):
        game[0][2], game[0][3] = game[0][3], game[0][2]
        game[0][6], game[0][7] = game[0][7], game[0][6]
    return (pool)
```

I need to flip specific index positions in every item in this list of lists, just the numerical values.

The structure would be:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] -> [0,1,3,2,4,5,7,6]
```

So for all the items, I need to flip the positions `[2] and [3]`, and `[6] and [7]`

For example:

```
[[0,1,3,2,0,3,1,2],"DlCo",""] -> [[0,1,2,3,0,3,2,1],"DlCo",""]
```

I thought this would be the way of doing it, but it doesnt work. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I still didn't get the final format. What are the "flipping rules"? In your examples, some elements were flipped, some were not, you didn't flip every position... And what would be "the way of doing it", that didn't work?

Comment: The elements in the list have their own structure, nothing is flipped. I need to flip the items in the mentioned position, so the rules are only 2for3 and 6for7 for the indexes. The way I tried is this `ListFlip()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
for game in range (0, len(pool)):
```

Should be:

```
for game in pool:
```

As the first only gets the index of each game in the pool, so indexing `game[0][2]` is invalid here.

Your code works fine now:

```
pool = [[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"ze","Zero"],
        [[0,0,3,0,3,0,0,0],"bd","BasicDilemma"],
        [[0,0,3,2,3,0,0,2],"lk","LowLock"],
        [[0,1,3,2,0,3,1,2],"DlCo",""],
        [[0,1,3,2,0,3,2,1],"DlPc",""],
        [[0,1,3,2,1,3,0,2],"DlAs",""],
        [[0,1,3,2,1,3,2,0],"DlHa",""],
        [[0,1,3,2,2,3,0,1],"DlSh",""],
        [[0,1,3,2,2,3,1,0],"DlNc",""]]

def ListFlip(pool):
    for game in pool:
        game[0][2], game[0][3] = game[0][3], game[0][2]
        game[0][6], game[0][7] = game[0][7], game[0][6]

    return pool

print(ListFlip(pool))
```

Which Outputs:

```
[[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'ze', 'Zero'], 
 [[0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0], 'bd', 'BasicDilemma'], 
 [[0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 2, 0], 'lk', 'LowLock'], 
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1], 'DlCo', ''], 
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2], 'DlPc', ''], 
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 0], 'DlAs', ''], 
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 0, 2], 'DlHa', ''], 
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 0], 'DlSh', ''], 
 [[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1], 'DlNc', '']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess I wouldnt spot this anytime soon!

Comment: No problem, you were just fetching the indices rather than the lists themselves.